# How to add backspace button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I started learning jQuery about a week ago So to test my knowledge I created a jQuery calculator i got everything right except the backspace button

i tried this

```
if (value === backspace) {
$(input).val($(input).val().substring(0, $(input).val().length - 1));

}
```

but it doesn't work

Here is my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" name="">
            <div class="btns">
                <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="1">
                <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="2">
                <input type="submit" name="btn3" value="3">
                <input type="submit" name="btn4" value="4">
                <input type="submit" name="btn5" value="5">
                <input type="submit" name="btn6" value="6">
                <input type="submit" name="btn7" value="7">
                <input type="submit" name="btn8" value="8">
                <input type="submit" name="btn9" value="9">
                <input type="submit" name="btn0" value="0">
                <input type="submit" name="plus" value="+">
                <input type="submit" name="minus" value="-">
                <input type="submit" name="mulpy" value="*">
                <input type="submit" name="div" value="/">
                <input type="submit" name="mod" value="%">
                <input type="submit" name="div" value="=">
                <input type="submit" name="reset" value="reset">
                <input type="submit" name="back" value="&larr;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background: #45D196;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #45D196 0%, #1C6EA4 44%, #A6C55F 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #45D196 0%, #1C6EA4 44%, #A6C55F 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #45D196 0%, #1C6EA4 44%, #A6C55F 100%);
}

.container {
width: 300px;
margin-top: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.btns,
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


input[type = "submit"] {
cursor: pointer;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;

}

input[type = "text"] {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
font-size: 30px;
outline: none;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #45D196;
}
```

And the Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


let input= $('input[type="text"]');

$(".btns").click(function(e) {
let $current_val = $(input).val();
let value = $(e.target).val();
$(input).val($current_val + value);
let backspace = $("input:last-child").val();

if (value === "reset") {
$(input).val("");

}

if (value === "=") {
let answer = eval($current_val);
$(input).val("");
$(input).val(answer);   
}

if (value === backspace) {
$(input).val($(input).val().substring(0, $(input).val().length - 1));

}






});





});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try if (value === "&larr;") instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code to add characters to the display is triggering before the backspace, so you are adding a backspace character to the display, then immediately removing it. You could just change `$(input).val($(input).val().substring(0, $(input).val().length - 1))` to `$(input).val($(input).val().substring(0, $(input).val().length - 2))` to get rid of both the backspace and the last number, but it probably makes more sense to restructure your code. 
Instead of a series of if-statements, try checking for special actions in an if-else chain **with the default action at the end**. Something like this

```
let value = $(e.target).val();
let backspace = $("input:last-child").val();
let $current_val = $(input).val();


if (value === "reset") {
    $(input).val("");

} else if (value === "=") {
    let answer = eval($current_val);
    $(input).val("");
    $(input).val(answer);
} else if (value === backspace) {
    $(input).val($(input).val().substring(0, $(input).val().length - 1));
} else {
    $(input).val($current_val + value);
}
```